# How to make binding between data-title attribute and text in an object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, data-binding

for the below posted code, it is part of a template of an angular .ts file.
i added data-title attribure so i can have a text like a tooltip when the button is hovered.
the problem i have now is, the value i want to set to data-title can be obtained via binding and i would like to apply a pipe on that value. it is defined in the angular .ts file as follows:

```
"TOOLTIP":{
    "EDIT_TOPOGRAPHY": "Edit Topography"
}
```

something as follows_:

```
 data-title= {{ TOOLTIP.EDIT_TOPOGRAPHY | pipe}}
```

how can make binding between data-title attribute and the aforementione text in the object "TOOLTIP" and apply a pipe

**code**:

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-icon"  data-title= {{ | pipe}} (click)="editTopography()" data-tooltip="text"> <clr-icon shape="pencil"></clr-icon></button>
```

**.ts file**:

```
"TOOLTIP":{
    "EDIT_TOPOGRAPHY": "Edit Topography"
}
```

Comment: Have a look: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nh474p

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap `data-title` to square brackets `[]`

So it will look like this

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-icon"  [attr.data-title]="variable | pipe" (click)="editTopography()" data-tooltip="text"> <clr-icon shape="pencil"></clr-icon></button>
```

You can read more about binding syntax [here](https://angular.io/guide/binding-syntax)

In your TS you are not declaring a variable that you could use for binding. To access this variable you should define it inside of component.

Typescript code

```
export class SomeComponent {
    public tooltip = {
       "TOOLTIP": {
         "EDIT_TOPOGRAPHY": "Edit Topography"
       }
    }
   ... 
}
```

Then you can access it in your HTML code

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-icon"  [attr.data-title]="tooltip.TOOLTIP.EDIT_TOPOGRAPHY | pipe" (click)="editTopography()" data-tooltip="text"> <clr-icon shape="pencil"></clr-icon></button>
```

Comment: hi..i slightly updated the question, would you please have a look

Comment: Could you please specify it?

Answer (score 0):

wrap interpolation in double quotes

<button class="btn btn-sm btn-icon"  data-title= "{{'LABEL' | pipe}}" (click)="editTopography()" data-tooltip="text">

data-title= "{{ | pipe}}"